# Is it possible to write to a .dll file on Windows with a USB output from a Pi?

Tags: raspbian, windows

I'm working on a project which requires data gathered on a Raspberry Pi to be written to a `.dll` file on a Windows machine.

The `.dll` file will be read by Unity to position the camera.

It's headtracking data so we need this to be transmitted very quickly, so doing it over Wi-Fi won't be fast enough. I haven't looked too much into doing it via Ethernet so if that's a good possibility let me know!

I know I'm basically asking if a Linux box can communicate to Windows via USB so sorry if it's really basic!

Comment: Do you know what a `dll` is? Any Linux machine can communicate with most hosts via a myriad of protocols. What you do on the host is up to you, and has nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: You may want to look at your architecture. Normally you write to a data file that data file may be accessed by a DLL, but you don;t normally write to the DLL.

Comment: As the others have stated, you're clearly confused as to the architecture of the system you're trying to use. `dll` files are a common file type on windows, and they're usually used as a precompilled library that's used by an application.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of stuff doesn't really make sense in your question.

Firstly, as you've asked, what is "writing" to a DLL?

The Raspberry Pi USB port, unfortunately, isn't a slave. So you wouldn't be able to use the Pi as a slave device. You would need some extra USB hardware to do so. Even though there might be some hacky/tricky way to use only USB communication, I doubt it would be efficient for data transfer.

What I would do, to communicate with Windows, is via Ethernet. It depends on the type of data you want to send, and your ability to code, but I think hosting a server based on sockets, either on Windows or the Pi, is the way to go. Then you'll just use the client, either on Windows or on the Pi, and send/receive the data to/from the server.

You can do that in whatever language suit you, be it C, JavaScript (very efficient with `socket.io`) or may be even Python, but it depends on the robustness and the speed of the communication that you need.

Comment: The Pi USB *is* a master, else you wouldn't be able to connect a keyboard, mouse and other peripherals - I think you mean that you can't slave it to a Windows machine, or vice versa?

Comment: Yes you're right ! I edited my post to make it right